# taking snaphot using lVM

Tags: filesystems, linux

While taking snapshot of a logical volume using lvcreate command, I found like this:

lvcreate --name test --snapshot --size=2M /dev/VolGroup/lv_root

I am confused what 'size' here actually means ? If it is to total size of snapshot to be created, how can /'s snapshot fit in 2Mb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LVM snapshot only needs as much space as it is different to the original LV. So, if you create a LVM snapshot of a 1.0GB volume, the snapshot size would be 0 (well, except some metadata I guess). If you're changing data on the original LV, say you downloaded a 200MB file, the LVM snapshot would be 200MB. If you have set the snapshot size to 2MB, that snapshot would now be unusable because it could not write the remaining 198MB.

Taken from the manual:

```
       -s, --snapshot
          Create  a snapshot logical volume (or snapshot) for an existing,
          so called original logical volume (or origin).   Snapshots  pro-
          vide  a  'frozen  image' of the contents of the origin while the
          origin can still be updated. They enable consistent backups  and
          online  recovery of removed/overwritten data/files. The snapshot
          does not need the same amount of storage the origin  has.  In  a
          typical  scenario,  15-20% might be enough. In case the snapshot
          runs out of storage, use lvextend(8) to  grow  it.  Shrinking  a
          snapshot  is  supported by lvreduce(8) as well. Run lvdisplay(8)
          on the snapshot in order to check how much data is allocated  to
          it.   Note  that a small amount of the space you allocate to the
          snapshot is used to track the locations of the chunks  of  data,
          so  you  should  allocate  slightly more space than you actually
          need and monitor the rate at which the snapshot data is  growing
          so you can avoid running out of space.
```